# What is the main purpose of the admin site?

Tags: python, django

Well I been working on Django for a short time as a backend developer (maintainant). And most of the Django sources that I work on, do not have the Django Admin Site.

However, when I look up any document of Django. There will be a big section relating about the Django Admin site.

So I wonder, what is the main purpose of the Django Admin Site, and in which scenario we gonna use it and in your case, how often you interact with Django Admin Site.

Comment: I hope the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#module-django.contrib.admin) itself self-explanatory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is useful for administering the site without coding but with a user-friendly GUI. You can register your models which will appear in the admin interface, which allows you to create or update instances. The interface is required for interactions that are not available to the normal user but only for administrators. It is powerful because it can be modified and extended very easily. For example in a newspaper or blog it can be used for managing articles, newsletter and inscriptions. In a social network or forum it can be used to manage: bans, reports, communications, user, privileges and more.

Answer (score 1):

It's a GUI of the database. It's useful, for example, when using a [2FA module](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth) with [QR code](https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/), it displays the QR code directly from the interface, zero extra code, super useful.

Basically, it's the best way of letting site admins touch things without them knowing how a database works. Wanna add a client to the DB when the site doesn't have a view for it because the end user can't add clients? Use Django admin. **It's a quick way of having native views of all the models of the DB without anyone having to code a view.**